# solr standalone: BasicAuth org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException

Tags: json, apache, solr, lucene, jetty

I have setup a security.json doc as per example in the solr examples in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Rule-Based+Authorization+Plugin.

But solr is throwing an error and doesn't get to read the security json which looks ok to me. security.json:

```
{
"authentication":{
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}]
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

Any help?

/usr/local/solr-6.5.0/server/logs/solr.log:

```
2017-04-25 17:45:03.530 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.3.14.v20161028
2017-04-25 17:45:03.870 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 6.5.0
2017-04-25 17:45:03.870 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in standalone mode on port 8984
2017-04-25 17:45:03.871 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: /usr/local/solr-6.5.0
2017-04-25 17:45:03.885 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2017-04-25T17:45:03.872Z
2017-04-25 17:45:03.885 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.StartupLoggingUtils Property solr.log.muteconsole given. Muting ConsoleAppender named CONSOLE
2017-04-25 17:45:03.900 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Using system property solr.solr.home: /usr/local/solr-6.5.0/server/solr
2017-04-25 17:45:03.908 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration from /usr/local/solr-6.5.0/server/solr/solr.xml
2017-04-25 17:45:04.181 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.u.UpdateShardHandler Creating UpdateShardHandler HTTP client with params: socketTimeout=600000&connTimeout=60000&retry=true
2017-04-25 17:45:04.193 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
2017-04-25 17:45:04.217 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Failed opening existing security.json file: /usr/local/solr-6.5.0/server/solr/security.json
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.getSecurityConfig(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reloadSecurityProperties(CoreContainer.java:611)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:483)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:237)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: Expected ',' or '}': char=",position=312 BEFORE='ssions":[{"name":"security-edit", "role":"admin"}] "' AFTER='user-role":{"solr":"admin"} }} '
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:356)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:958)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getObject(ObjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:57)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getObject(ObjectBuilder.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.Utils.fromJSON(Utils.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandler$SecurityConfig.setData(SecurityConfHandler.java:311)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.getSecurityConfig(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:58)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shawn Heisey-2 at solr-user@lucene.apache.org.

The example in the solr docs was a badly written json which had I checked in a json parse checker or my IDE would have been revealed.

This was a valid error thrown by the json parser of course.